# How can I use "for loop" to output dataframe in order?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I want to output dataframes with for loop.

For example, a list (it is just a metaphor)

```
a=[1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in range(3):
   a[i]
```

Like this, I want to output "dataframes" in order with for loop. Can I do it? How can I do this?

Comment: Please add an example `dataframe` and an expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are no sample dataframes you have provided and assuming you want to just print(output) them. The same methodology could be applied.

Store all the dataframe identifiers in a list and print them using for loop. Here df[s] represent 3 separates dataframe.

```
lis = [df,df1,df2]
for i in lis:
   print(i)
```

Comment: Well, I really do not even imagine that dataframes can be in a list. Thanks for your kind answer.